# Why encode does not always work?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a Python code that tries to read RSS sources written in Cyrillic letters (for example Russian). This is the code that I use:

```
import feedparser
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

d=feedparser.parse(source_url)

# Make a loop over the entries of the RSS feed.
for e in d.entries:
    # Get the title of the news.
    title = e.title
    title = title.replace(' ','%20')
    title = title.encode('utf-8')

    # Get the URL of the entry.
    url = e.link
    url = url.encode('utf-8')


    # Make the request. 
    address = 'http://example.org/save_link.php?title=' + title + '&source=' + source_name + '&url=' + url

    # Submit the link.
    req = Request(address)
    f = urlopen(req)
```

I use `encode('utf-8')` since the titles are given in Cyrillic letters and it works fine. An example of the RSS source is [here](http://k.img.com.ua/rss/ua/news.xml). The problem appears when I try to read the list of the RSS sources from another URL. In more details, there is a web-page that contains a list of RSS sources (URL of the sources as well as their names given in Cyrillic letters). An example of the list is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'>

ua, Корреспондент, http://k.img.com.ua/rss/ua/news.xml
ua, Українська Правда, http://www.pravda.com.ua/rss/

</body>
</html>
```

The problem appears when I try to apply encode('utf-8') to the Cyrillic letters given in this document. I get an `UnicodeDecodeError`. Does anybody knows why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`encode` will only give `UnicodeDecodeError` if you supply it a `str` object which it then tries to decode to `unicode`; see http://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeDecodeError.

You need to decode the `str` object to `unicode` first:

```
name = name.decode('utf-8')
```

This will take a `str` in UTF-8 encoding and give you a `unicode` object.

It works for the code that you posted because `feedparser` returns feed data already decoded to `unicode`.

Comment: But why `encode` works with the Cyrillic titles from the RSS source and it does not work with the Cyrillic names of the sources given in the list of the RSS sources?

Comment: @Roman presumably because you haven't decoded the names in the list.

Comment: @ecatmur, but I also haven't not decoded the titles of the link from the RSS feeds and it was fine. Do you think that they have been already decoded on the web page or feed parser decoded them? Also it is not clear how should I decode the names. name.decode('utf-8')?

Comment: @Roman yes, `feedparser` decodes the web page and returns everything as `unicode`.  `names.decode('utf-8')` should work fine.